# How to work with ipv6 proxies presented as ipv4?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, ipv6

I have an ipv6 proxy like https://user:pass@185.221.153.157:21199. How can I work with them in python? This code doesn't work, it just stucks:

```
import requests

proxy = 'https://user:pass@185.221.153.157:21199'
proxies = {
    'http': proxy,
    'https': proxy
}

print(requests.get('https://icanhazip.com', proxies=proxies).content)
```

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate, incompatible protocols. An IPv6 host cannot send anything to an IPv4 address. Your IPv6 proxy needs an IPv6 address.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was told that they are converted on the server

Comment: An IPv6 host cannot send packets to an IPv4 address. IPv6 packets use IPv6 addressing. IPv4 and IPv6 are completely, separate, incompatible protocols. Yes, something may be able to receive IPv6 packets at an IPv6 address, strip off the IPv6 headers from the packet payload, fix the transports protocol checksums for IPv4, put IPv4 headers on the payload, and send out IPv4 packets, but IPv6 talks to an IPv6 address, and IPv4 talks to an IPv4 address. You cannot use IPv4 addressing in IPv6 packets, and vice versa. The converting device would need both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and stacks.